# Send a hidden ID input field with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

With this AJAX script, I'm trying to send the content of contentText and contentID.

Just sending contentTEXT works, but I want to send the ID as well, so I can comment on the original post.

But it doesn't work!

myData looks like this when it semi works:

```
> var myData = '?content_txt='+$("#contentText").val(),
> '&content_id='+$("#contentId").val(); //build a post data structure
```

But i want it to be something like this, i think

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {

    //##### send add record Ajax request to response.php #########  $("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {           e.preventDefault();             if($("#contentText").val()==='')            {
                alert("Please enter some text!");
                return false;           }
                        $("#FormSubmit").hide(); //hide submit button           $("#LoadingImage").show(); //show loading image

            var myData = '?content_txt='+$("#contentText").val(), '&content_id='+$("#contentId").val(); //build a post data structure
            jQuery.ajax({           type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET            url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls             contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",             dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.          data:myData, //Form variables           success:function(response){
                $("#responds").append(response);
                $("#contentText").val(''); //empty text field on successful
                $("#FormSubmit").show(); //show submit button
                $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image

            },          error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                $("#FormSubmit").show(); //show submit button
                $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image
                alert(thrownError);             }           });     });

    //##### Send delete Ajax request to response.php #########  $("body").on("click", "#responds .del_button", function(e) {         e.preventDefault();         var clickedID = this.id.split('-'); //Split ID string (Split works as PHP explode)          var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array          var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure
                $('#item_'+DbNumberID).addClass( "sel" ); //change background of this element by adding class       $(this).hide(); //hide currently clicked delete button
                    jQuery.ajax({           type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET            url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls             dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.          data:myData, //Form variables           success:function(response){
                //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
                $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut();           },          error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);             }           });     });

}); </script>
```

My form I'm trying to use

```
<form class="form-horizontal" accept-charset="utf-8">
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo WORDING_ADD_A_COMMENT; ?></legend>
<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">                     
    <textarea name="content_txt" id="contentText" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="<?php echo WORDING_COMMENT_PLACEHOLDER; ?>"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="content_id" id="contentId" value="<?php echo $_GET['topic_id']; ?>"/>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Button -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="FormSubmit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo WORDING_BUTTON_COMMENT_BOX; ?></button>
    <img src="images/loading.gif" id="LoadingImage" style="display:none" />
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var variable = {
 'content_txt': $("#contentText").val(),
 'content_id': $("#contentId").val() 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
       var myData = '?content_txt='+$("#contentText").val()+'&content_id='+$("#contentId").val();
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @jurgemaister I will take care of this in future. Thanks for bringing this into my consideration. :)

Answer (score 0):

You only use `?` and `&` when you manually build a query string and in that case you would need to encode your values as well.

When you send the data as a parameter, the easiest solution is to generate an object. That will be encoded automatically by jQuery:

```
//build a post data structure
var myData = { 'content_txt': $("#contentText").val(),
               'content_id': $("#contentId").val() };
```

As you are using a form, you can also serialize the form:

```
var myData = $('.form-horizontal').serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

data:'content_id='+ $("#contentId").val()+ '&content_txt='+ $("#contentText").val() ,